# How to fetch Paperclip photo urls in a SQL Query - Rails 3.1, Paperclip

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, paperclip

I am trying to write an API for an app using rails as the backend, which shows meal listing. Each meal item shows a name and photo. For the API, I am trying to return a JSON array, which contains all photo urls associated with a meal model and ordered by highest ranking through a sql query. I am unsure what I am suppose to put in the SELECT statement.

How the model looks:

```
Meal
  has_many :photos
  #other attributes
end

Photo
  belongs_to :meal
  # paperclip stuff
end
```

All photos are uploaded through paperclip. The setup is based on [Emerson Lackey's tutorial](http://www.emersonlackey.com/article/paperclip-with-rails-3). I am using PostgreSQL as the database.

If there is a better way please also let me know.

Answer (score 1):

something like (untested):

```
render :json=>@meal.photos.all(:order=>'whatever').map(&:photo_url)
```